# Getting Android device locale with JavaScript in Tasker

Tags: javascript, android, locale

I'm trying to get the device locale by running the JavaScript in Tasker, the script should assign the locale to variable.
The whole JavaScript file looks like following:

```
var locale = Locale.getDefault();
```

But variable **locale** is empty.
I've also tried

```
var locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
```

with the same result.
Also tried to use **String** instead of **var** but that gave me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.
In Tasker, you can run a Shell command, so I ran

```
getprop persist.sys.locale
```

and passed its result to a global value.